# Formula to Sum "amount" column in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a column name as "Amount" in CR. I need to sum that column.

I created a new formula and tried `sum( { MycolumnName} )` and it says

> "A number field or currency amount field is required here"

Is there any way to apply conversion in formula itself.

Comment: don't worry.  Crystal-reports questions are a low-traffic area to begin with, plus its the holidays, so responses may come slowly.  Asking for a response ASAP usually doesn't encourage answers, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why create a formula when you can just create a summary field by selecting your column and going to the menu and selecting `Insert Summary`, `Insert Subtotal` or `Insert Grand Total` depending on your needs?  You can place the summary field in a group section as a subtotal, or in the report footer as a grand total.

If you need to apply a conversion in the formula, you can use `CCur` like this:

```
sum( CCur({ MycolumnName}) )
```

More information on converting types in Crystal Reports can be found [here](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Chapter06_XI.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. But using the formula you mention it gives me the error saying that " A field was expected here"

Comment: @Romil - Try `ToNumber()` instead, or double-check and see what the data type of the field is in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type `xs:string` to `xs:decimal` of the column `MycolumnName` in `xs:element` in .xsd page